Quantum sensing using Ion penning traps[[ODF, Dicke states and pi/2 pulse]]
I am reading the article
https://www.science.org/doi/full/10.1126/science.abi5226
It's about Quantum sensing in ion penning traps.
Question 1.
Does the axial mode of the penning trap have nothing to do with the COM mode in the paper?
Or is it the same thing?
Also, is there any literature that explains nicely about the ODF (Optical Diple Force)? I'm having difficulties understanding the exact process of how the excitation of COM mode leads to the entanglement of the spin and COM mode..
Question 2.
Intially, there is a optical pumping that prepares all the ions in the spin up state.
Then, they apply a pi/2 pulse to align the spin to the x axis (Superposition of spin up and down).
And then, the spin and COM mode state can be represented as

Where the first term is the bosonic vacuum, I do not understand the each term.
I guess the first term is in the Fock state and second term is in Dicke state.
But then is the COM mode represented as the vacuum and spin in Dicke states..? Also is it N/2 because in the Dicke states, J=N/2?
Question 3.


This is the ODF Hamiltonian recasted as the squeezed Hamiltonian. (I don't 100% understand what 'recast' to squeezed Hamiltonian means)
I only say the quadrature operator when it doesn't include the term of the spin. So I don't understand how this came to be. Will there be any nice literature on this?
Also the whole point of this was to show that the Action of the Hamiltonian of ODF (Originally, it was explained to entangle the spin and COM mode)  is to generate squeezing along the quadrature phase space.
How does this 'entangle' and 'squeeze state' get linked?
All of the Answers doesn't need to answer directly, but recommendation of literature will help .
Thanks
